# jQuery - find class of radio element for validation

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button, selection

I need to target all radio elements with the class of 'error' and change the colour of the surrounding 'td' element, this is not working for me :

```
$(':radio').hasClass('error').closest("td").css("background", "#FBDDDD");
```

or

```
$(':radio.error').closest("td").css("background", "#FBDDDD");
```

is there some other way of checking a radio/checkbox elements class?

Comment: You say > class of 'required' but then your code refers to a class of `error`. Can you clarify?

Comment: Actually the second one that you have there should work. 'code'$(':radio.error').closest("td").css("background", "#FBDDDD");'code'
that will grab any element with an attribute type="radio". Maybe you have another problem. are there any javascript errors? Is the html structured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**parent**](http://api.jquery.com/parents) function

```
$(this).parents("td:first");
```

Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/kH7NN/2/

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$("input:radio.error").closest("td").css("background-color", "#FBDDDD");
```